# A particle on a ring: orthogonality of eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

Let us consider the quantum-mechanical problem---a particle on a ring of a circumference as $2\pi$ with a magnetic flux $A$ inserted through it: 
\begin{eqnarray}
H=(-i\partial_\phi-A)^2, 
\end{eqnarray}
which has the eigenstate wave functions as
\begin{eqnarray}
\psi^{(A)}_n(\phi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(in\phi), 
\end{eqnarray}
where the magnetic flux $A$ is treated as a parameter and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ due to a periodic boundary condition $\phi\sim\phi+2\pi$.

If $A_1\neq A_2$, then $\psi_n^{(A_1)}$ and $\psi_n^{(A_2)}$ are orthogonal since they have different energy eigenvalues as $E_1=(n-A_1)^2$ and $E_2=(n-A_2)^2$, respectively. Or we can prove such an orthogonality by showing their gauge-invariant kinetic angular momentum $(-i\partial_\phi-A_{1,2})$ being different.

My question is: how could we directly prove such orthogonality by wave functions $\psi_n^{(A_{1,2})}(\phi)$'s in a straightforward manner rather than by some gauge-invariant observable? For the case that $(A_1-A_2)\in\mathbb{Z}$, it is easy to do so since we can apply a large gauge transformation so that $A_1$ can be transformed to $A_2$ followed by doing the inner product of wave functions. But how to resolve this question generally, e.g. $(A_1-A_2)\neq0\mod\mathbb{Z}$, by wave functions?

Comment: Couldnt you just calculate the scalar product? But looking at your wavefunction it doesnt seem to depend on A (at least the right side of the second equation). So then they are not orthogonal.

Comment: @lalala The explicit form of wave function cannot be considered separately. For instance, if $A_1=A_2+1$, then $A_1$ is gauge equivalent to $A_2$ by a gauge transformation, which will also transform the wave function. The transformed $\psi_n^{(A_1)}$ is orthogonal with $\psi_n^{(A_2)}$. I do not know the solution for general situations.

Comment: @lalala For general cases that $A_1$ is not gauge equivalent to $A_2$, there does not exist such a gauge transformation. How to deal with it is what I am being asking about.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. What I think you're saying is: "for two physically distinct Hamiltonians, how can I prove that all energy eigenstates of the first Hamiltonian are orthogonal to all energy eigenstates of the second?" However, this statement is obviously false, so you must mean something else.

Comment: @knzhou You are right, and I should not have used the energy to raise the question. But instead, if I use the kinetic angular momentum $(-i\partial_\phi-A)$, the two states have different values. Can I use it to argue that the eigenstates are orthogonal?